# How to obtain CIDR IP notation from IP and subnet using Perl

Tags: perl, networking

Is there a Perl function that, given an IP address and subnet mask, can return the CIDR notation of the subnet the IP belongs to?

For example, assuming I have the IP `192.168.1.23` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`, I want to obtain the value `192.168.1.0/24`.

Or if I have `192.168.1.23` with subnet mask `255.255.255.224` I want `192.168.1.0/27` and so on.

I could eventually build a function that does so, but I find hard to believe there isn't something that does this already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a prepackaged solution, you can use the `addrandmask2cidr` function from [Net::CIDR](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CIDR).

If you want to roll your own, the basic algorithm is to count the number of set bits in the mask to get the value after the slash (e.g., 255.255.255.0 is 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 in binary, 24 bits set, therefore CIDR /24) and do a logical-and (`&`) of the address with the mask to get the network's base address.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend that you use the [`NetAddr::IP`](https://p3rl.org/NetAddr::IP) module. It's a simple matter of constructing an object with the required IP address and net mask and calling the `network` method on it

It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use NetAddr::IP;

say make_cidr(qw/ 192.168.1.23  255.255.255.0 /);
say make_cidr(qw/ 192.168.1.23  255.255.255.224 /);

sub make_cidr {
    my ($addr, $mask) = @_;
    my $net = NetAddr::IP->new($addr, $mask);
    $net->network;
}
```

#### output

```
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.0/27
```